# How to prove $H_1(\mathbb{C}/\Lambda, \mathbb{Z})$ to the lattice $\Lambda$ ,$\gamma \mapsto \int_\gamma dz$ is well defined?

Tags: homology-cohomology, elliptic-curves, group-isomorphism, integer-lattices

Let fix an arbitraly lattice of $\mathbb{C}$ and call it Λ.

How to prove $H_1(\mathbb{C}/\Lambda, \mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to the lattice $\Lambda$ via the map $\gamma \mapsto \int_\gamma dz$
?

If once the map is proved to be well defined, the map is obviously group homomorphism and injection, and surjection may be managed.

So, I want to check the map is well defined .

Why $ \int_\gamma dz$ is in $Λ$?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you can possibly know that this map is injective and surjective without knowing that it takes values in $\Lambda$.

Comment: Injectivity is obvious because integral value is determined only by homology class of the closed path.

Comment: That is not what injectivity says (it's roughly the converse of it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the loop $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ and lift it to a path $\bar{\gamma}$ in $\mathbb{C}$.  Since $\gamma$ is a loop, the endpoints of $\bar{\gamma}$ must differ by an element of $\Lambda$.  Since we're integrating $dz$, the integral will just be the difference between the two endpoints, and thus an element of $\Lambda$.

Comment: Your $dz$ is holomorphic differential on C/Λ, right? Then, why  ∮dz on $r$ is equal to ∮dz on $r~$ ( Here, $dz$ is holomorphic differential on C)?

Comment: @Neronoggshafareivh: Because by definition $dz$ on $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ is the differential that pulls back to $dz$ on $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Let $π:C→C/Λ:r~→r $ be natural projection,, then, pull back of $dz$ by $π$ is π*(dz)＝dz⚪︎π＝dz, right ? ( I'm a bit confused)